# Switching between symbologies for two different fields quickly in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, color

I'm trying to quickly switch between two different coloring schemes for my map quickly. I have a map filled with several polygons that are colored according to a particular field. The image for that is attached here:

[image]

I would like to introduce another coloring scheme for these same polygons based on a different field. I cannot figure out how to quickly toggle between the two color schemes without resetting my symbology preferences each time. I suppose I could copy the data layer and introduce that new color scheme there, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is by doing as you suggest in your question:

> copy the data layer and introduce that new color scheme there

That way it is one click to turn off one scheme and another to turn off the other whenever you wish to switch between them.